# R - how to prevent row.names when selecting rows from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, row

Suppose I create a dataframe (just to keep it simple):

```
testframe <- data.frame( a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c(5,6,7,8))
```

Thus, I have two variables (columns) and four cases (rows).

If I select some of the rows BEGINNING WITH THE FIRST row, i get some kind of subset of the dataframe, e.g.:

```
testframe2 <- testframe[1:2,] #selecting the first two rows
```

But if i do the same with a row NOT BEGINNING WITH THE FIRST ROW, I get another column containing the row numbers of the original dataframe.

```
testframe3 <- testframe[3:4,] #selecting the last two rows
```

leads to:

```
  a b
3 3 7
4 4 8
```

What can I do to prevent the new row.names variable in the first place? I know that I can delete it afterwards but maybe it is still possible to avoid it from the beginning.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not reproducible. When I run your code I even get a different dataset than you.

Comment: The code was reproducible for me.  The `row.names` column appears if you use `View(testframe3)`.

Comment: @spdickson, `View` is not mentioned in the question. And _if_ `View` is used, see `?View`: "If there are row names on the data frame that are not `1:nrow`, they are displayed in a separate first column called `row.names`.

Comment: ok, thats true. If I look at the specifics of the dataframe, it's still 2 colums, but with the view-command it seems like you have a new first column with the row.names. But then I wonder why this only happens to the second command and not for the command where I select the first two rows? EDIT: but if I want to edit the new dataframe: edit(testframe3) then I definetly get a new first column "row.names"

Comment: Guys use your intuition. This is just a formatting issue, which I put down to the OP being relatively new on the site (and manually constructing the output data). Cut them some slack - they provided a MWE. The *problem* (I wouldn't say documented behaviour is a problem per se) is easily reproducible, but it just doesn't *look* exactly the same using the posted code. It's pedantic to say its not reproducible.

Comment: @ SimonO101. Yes, after the question was edited maybe. Before the edit the output was substantially different and confusing. So my comment was not pedantic at all, I just wanted enough information to help.

Comment: @JT85 I made the edit *because* the comment was pedantic. In the original you copy the first line you get a two column dataframe with 4 rows numbered 1:4, you make testframe3 you get a two column data frame with two rows numbered 3 and 4. The columns don't have the same name as the example output? Come on!!!! It's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @deschen, you mentioned `edit` in your comment. In that function you can use the argument `edit.row.names = FALSE`. Then row names are not displayed as a separate column. There is no such argument in `View` and therefore the 'feature' I mentioned in my previous comment kicks in...

Comment: @ SimonO101 Like the question was asked it seemed that a third column appeared that contained row.names ("I get another column containing..." ) and that this was the problem. So it was just a misinterpretation of the question due to the output shown in combination with the text. So relax...

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that display of rownames can be suppressed with `print(testframe3,row.names=FALSE)`

Answer (score 4):

It copies the `row.names` from the original dataset. Just rename the rows using `rownames<-` like this...

```
rownames( testframe3 ) <- seq_len( nrow( testframe3 ) )
#   a b
# 1 3 7
# 2 4 8
```

Programmatically `seq_len( nrow( x ) )` is preferred to say `1:nrow( x )` because looks what happens in edge cases where you select a `data.frame` of zero rows...

```
df <- testframe[0,]
# [1] a b
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
rownames(df) <- seq_len( nrow( df ) ) #  No error thrown - returns a length 0 vector of rownames

#  But...
rownames(df) <- 1:nrow( df )
# Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
#   invalid 'row.names' length

#  Because...
1:nrow( df )
# [1] 1 0
```

Alternatively you can do it in one by wrapping the subset in a call to `data.frame` but this is really inefficient if you want to derive the number of rows programmatically (because you will have to subset twice) and I don't recommend it over the `rownames<-` method:

```
data.frame( testframe[3:4,] , row.names = 1:2 )
#  a b
#1 3 7
#2 4 8
```

Comment: Or just `rownames( testframe3 ) <- NULL`

Comment: Well, I see the point and as I mentioned in m original post, of course you can delete the rownames afterwards. I just got confused, when I saw the new variable for the dataframe of row 3 and 4 but not for rows 1 and 2 and again: using the edit-command definetly shows the new column rownames and I still wonder if I can avoid these frm the beginning on, not just deleting it afterwards.

Comment: @deschen see my edit at the bottom, but really better to edit afterwards. honestly!!! :-)

Comment: If you say so, I believe you. It was just a question, if I can avoid this second step. If it is not possible, at least I now know it. ;-)